# Recommendation for robust, customizable, open source, Java servlet-based forum software?

Tags: untagged

There is a lot of forum software out there, but it seems to me that a lot of the popular choices are PHP-based.  And for my project, I'd like something based on Java servlets so my team can make customizations to it.

Another important feature is that I can completely change the pages to hide unwanted elements without too much work.  So I'm looking either for a template system or easily editable scripts (i.e. JSPs) that have a clean view separation.  Just having skin changes or CSS customization is not enough.  I understand that if I have open source, I can change anything I want, but my point is that it should be *easy* and not requiring mastery of a complex code base.

Finally, I want something that has been around for at least a year and deployed on some high-traffic sites.  Clustering support (one database, multiple web servers) is highly desirable.  Up-time is crucial since I have an SLA to support.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from one of my colleagues about [jforum](http://jforum.net/index.jsp). He said a while ago he integrated it in a java web based application.

HTH

Comment: As far as I can gather, the servlet-based pickings really are thin.  jForum does seem like one of the best choices though.